# Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.(breakurl) \burl will be just a synonym of \url. on input line 48

Tags: urls, springernature

How to remove the following warning?

```
Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.

(breakurl)                \burl will be just a synonym of \url.
(breakurl)                 on input line 48.
```

This is my code before the \begin{document}

```
%\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip,skip=0.5\abovecaptionskip]{caption}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{verbatim}
% \usepackage{subfiles}
\hyphenation{presents}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{3pt}
\date{February 2022}
%%% journal %%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Elsevier bibliography styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% To change the style, put a % in front of the second line of the current style and
%% remove the % from the second line of the style you would like to use.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Numbered
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

%% Numbered without titles
%\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}

%% Harvard
%\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% Vancouver numbered
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}

%% Vancouver name/year
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% APA style
%\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% AMA style
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
%\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{3pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{3pt} %%% 3pt 

\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: well as the message says: breakurl is useless with pdflatex, so simply don't load it.

Comment: I remove it, but it still don't work

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How did you remove it and what is not working? The package is loaded by the document class. So you would need to comment it out there. However, fiddling with document classes provided by editors and printing houses is probably a bad idea in general. So, I would just ignore this warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message about `\burl` being treated as a synonym for `\url` is a warning message, *not* an error message. You needn't doing anything about it -- especially if there are no `\burl` directives in the body of your document.

If you really can't stand getting this innocuous warning message, I suggest you open the file `sn-jnl.cls` in a text editor and find the following code chunk:

```
\gdef\breakurldefns{%
\if@pdflatex\else%
  \RequirePackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}%
  \let\href\burlalt%
\fi}%
\breakurldefns%
```

Then, either comment out (or delete) this entire chunk or, more simply, its final instruction, *viz.*,

```
\breakurldefns%
```

Comment: excellent answer!!

Answer (score 1):

To suppress the warning load the class with the option `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass[pdflatex]{sn-jnl}
\begin{document}
xxxx

\end{document}
```